# mysql workbench *reverse engineer* is not connecting tables graphically. How to fix?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I thought that previously when I reverse engineered databases, mySql Workbench figured out the relationships from the id names and connected the tables leading to an awesome ERD, even when the foreign key constraint clauses don't exist and they are just used through the fields (xxxx_id) have the foreign key values.

However currently, when I pick various databases (I create them in rails) and try to import them I end up with this nasty looking smodge:

[image]

Instead of:

[image]

Comment: MySQL Workbench figures out the relationships when they exist, as `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.

Comment: When no relationships exist, it doesn't guess anything. Note that even a human would only **guess** that `survey_sections.survey_header_id` is an FK to `survey_headers (id)`. And he could be wrong.

Comment: Some people add an `_id` to an FK column. Some use `id`, others use `tablename_id`, others use `tablenameID`, etc... as a PK name. The list is endless. And what about compound PK and FKs? What if the constraint should be towards a `UNIQUE` and not towards a `PRIMARY` key? How should WOrkbench (or anyone) guess?

Comment: Sure, it seems like a few dialog boxes or settings could address the **most common** scenarios of othertableID othertable_ID, etc. and no compound keys used for joins.  The possibilities are endless sure, but the most common ones are out there.

Comment: The database I am looking at ALWAYS has othertablename_id as it is rails, so no guessing required and when I add the lines in manually I do the exact same thing every time, at least for the basic 1 to many's (which is the majority).  self-referential's might be tricky.

Comment: Actually, there is an additional `s` at the end of the tables which is missing at the FK column names that reference those tables' PKs.

Comment: What could be done is a script to create those FKs (based on these specs) and then let Workbench reverse engineer.

Comment: I wrote a script to reverse engineer rails generated schemas and dump then into graphviz.  The logic was simple, but the resulting graph was unwieldy. Ypercubes idea of generating a new mysql schema with the constraints in place is a good one, which I think that I will try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL Workbench does not have the capability to "infer" the relationships from table column names, or MyISAM tables. It requires that the constraints be defined in the database or SQL script being reverse engineered.

Answer (score 4):

For any rails coder who finds this, you can use the [immigrant](https://github.com/jenseng/immigrant) gem. This generates a migration that builds all missing foreign key constraints. It uses [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner), which provides helper methods for foreign key constraints. Then workbench should be able to build the relationships.